# sudoers NOPASSWD not working - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, sudoers, visudo

I know this question was often asked before, but it's not possible for me to get it working.

I want to shutdown the system without entering a password with user `holmer`

I added the following line
`holmer ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown /usr/bin/timedatectl /usr/sbin/reboot`
with `sudo visudo` to `/etc/sudoers`.

This is actually the file `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# Disable sudo password for shutdown and timedatectl for user holmer
holmer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown /usr/bin/timedatectl /usr/sbin/reboot
```

I also tried to add a file with the line to `/etd/sudoers.d/`. - It also not worked.
If i uncomment the `#` of the line `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`, I get an error message.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Now you should be able to execute `sudo -n /sbin/shutdown /usr/bin/timedatectl /usr/sbin/reboot` without password.

Answer (score 2):

Commands in the sudoers file should be comma-separated. Try this:

```
holmer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown,/usr/bin/timedatectl,/usr/sbin/reboot
```